# MySQL Subquery Truncating Result with NULLIF

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    NULLIF(MAX(t.date),'2019-01-15') AS ended
FROM 
    totals t
```

This query correctly outputs a date:

```
> 2019-01-01
```

But if I reference this query inside of a subquery like so:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT 
        NULLIF(MAX(t.date),'2019-01-15') AS ended
    FROM 
        totals t) AS a
```

This version incorrectly produces a truncated result:

```
> 201
```

Can someone help me to understand this behavior and how best to work around it?

**Additional Notes:** 
I am running MySQL version: "5.7.25 MySQL Community Server"

For anyone wanting to test this out, here is an example of a simple test table that is affected by this problem:

```
CREATE TABLE `totals` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `value` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`)
);
INSERT INTO `totals` VALUES ('2018-01-01',2000000),('2019-01-01',3000000);
```

Comment: This looks to be an artifact to me.  Please include some sample data in your question.  Is `date` a text column?

Comment: Yes it is 'date' type. I added an edit that includes a simple table that you can use to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here appears to be a subtle converting/casting issue happening within `NULLIF`.  First, here is a version of your query which does in fact work as expected:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT NULLIF(MAX(t.date), STR_TO_DATE('2019-01-15', '%Y-%m-%d') AS ended
    FROM totals t
) AS a
```

What is happening with your current query is that MySQL is converting the call to `MAX(t.date)` to text, to match the text literal `'2015-01-15'`.  By ensuring that both arguments to `NULLIF` are date type, you get the behavior you want.

As for *why* we are seeing `201` as the string result from the call to `NULLIF`, I don't have an explanation.  But, I can cite the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif) for `NULLIF` here:

> Returns NULL if expr1 = expr2 is true, otherwise returns expr1. This is the same as CASE WHEN expr1 = expr2 THEN NULL ELSE expr1 END.

It is a general rule in SQL that both the if and else branches of a `CASE` expression should always have the same type.  Actually, if we violate this rule, in most databases the `CASE` expression won't even compile.  Applying this to `NULLIF` means that we should always make sure that both arguments have the same type.  Breaking from this rule *might* run on MySQL (similar to doing a non ANSI compliant `GROUP BY` with full mode turned off), but it is not something we should choose if we can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there's implicit datatype conversions happening.

As a workaround, I would take the return from the `NULLIF` function and convert/cast it back to `DATE` datatype.  Simplest would be to wrap it in `DATE()` function.

```
SELECT 
    DATE( NULLIF(MAX(t.date),'2019-01-15') ) AS ended
    ^^^^^                                  ^
```

---

We could also try converting the string literal, convert that to a DATE, and see if that fixes the problem:

```
SELECT
    NULLIF(MAX(t.date), DATE('2019-01-15') ) AS ended
                        ^^^^^            ^
```

---

Or we can do both:

```
SELECT 
    DATE( NULLIF(MAX(t.date), DATE('2019-01-15') ) ) AS ended
                              ^^^^^            ^
    ^^^^^                                          ^
```

There are other expressions we can use for the datatype conversion such as  `CAST()`, `CONVERT()`, or `STR_TO_DATE()`.

Or we could just use the simple `+ INTERVAL 0 DAY` trick. e.g.

```
SELECT 
    NULLIF(MAX(t.date),'2019-01-15' + INTERVAL 0 DAY ) + INTERVAL 0 DAY AS ended
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```